# FluentValidation implicit child validation using manual validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation

[Reading the documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#implicit-vs-explicit-child-property-validation) it appears that in .NET Core you can do implicit child properties validation with:

```
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => {
    fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
});
```

Unfortunately I'm not working with MVC directly so I have to call `Validate` myself (`IValidator<T>` instances are registered by myself with Scrutor). Is there a similar setting for manually validating nested fields as well as top-level fields (using .NET Core DI)?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by manual validation?

Comment: @Shymep Manually calling the `Validate(...)` method on an instance of `IValidator<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the FluentValidation source code you will notice that the `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` option uses the Asp.Net mechanism of validating nested properties so it won't work for manual validation.

You can write a helper or extension method that uses reflection and the `IValidatorFactory` service  to do nested validation:

```
public static async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateImplicitAsync<TReq>(this TReq request, IValidatorFactory factory)
            where TReq: class
{
    var result = new ValidationResult();
    await ValidateRecursively(request, factory, result);
    return result;
}

static async Task ValidateRecursively(
            object obj, 
            IValidatorFactory factory, 
            ValidationResult result)
{
    if(obj == null) { return; }
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    IValidator validator = factory.GetValidator(t);
    if(validator == null) { return; }
    ValidationResult r = await validator.ValidateAsync(new ValidationContext<object>(obj));
    foreach(var error in r.Errors)
    {
        result.Errors.Add(error);
    }
    foreach(var prop in t.GetProperties())
    {
        object childValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        await ValidateRecursively(childValue, factory, result);
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
public class MyService {
    readonly IValidatorFactory factory;
    
    public MyService(IValidatorFactory factory){
       this.factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task Handle(MyModel model){
       ValidationResult validationResult = await model.ValidateImplicitAsync(factory);
       // ... etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to define a base class for your validators, which itself handles the recursive validation.

I needed this specifically so that the validators run in a nested way, and the errors follow the structure of the object (e.g. `request.account.name: 'Name' must not be empty`).

This is the implementation:

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using FluentValidation;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Example.Validation;


public class RecursiveValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public RecursiveValidator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void ValidateMembers(Type allowedType)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties()) {
            if (allowedType.IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType)) {
                ValidateMember(propertyInfo.PropertyType, propertyInfo.Name, allowedType);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ValidateMember(Type fieldType, string propertyName, Type allowedType)
    {
        var lambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "request");
        var lambdaBody = Expression.Property(lambdaParameter, propertyName);
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Lambda(lambdaBody, lambdaParameter);

        typeof(RecursionHelper)
            .GetMethod(nameof(RecursionHelper.ValidateMember), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)!
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), fieldType)
            .Invoke(obj: null, new object[] { this, serviceProvider, propertyExpression, allowedType });
    }

    private static class RecursionHelper
    {
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public static void ValidateMember<TMessage, TProperty>(
            AbstractValidator<TMessage> validator,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            Expression<Func<TMessage, TProperty>> expression,
            Type allowedType
        )
        {
            // Discovers and adds registered validators for the given type
            var fieldValidators = serviceProvider.GetServices<IValidator<TProperty>>().ToList();
            var rule = validator.RuleFor(expression);
            foreach (var fieldValidator in fieldValidators) {
                rule.SetValidator(fieldValidator);
            }

            // If no validators are found, create one and let it recurse
            if (fieldValidators.Count == 0) {
                var recursiveValidator = new RecursiveValidator<TProperty>(serviceProvider);
                recursiveValidator.ValidateMembers(allowedType);
                rule.SetValidator(recursiveValidator);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, inherit from `RecursiveValidator<T>` instead of `ValidateMembers<T>`, and .

Then call `ValidateMembers(Type allowedType)` when you want it to validate all members.

```cs
class UserValidator : RecursiveValidator<User> {
    public UserValidator(IServiceProvider services) : base(services) {
        // Recurse on specific types
        ValidateMembers(typeof(Address));
        ValidateMembers(typeof(PhoneNumber));

        // Recurse on all members of a baseclass, e.g. IMessage
        ValidateMembers(typeof(IMessage));

        RuleFor(user => user.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

> Note, recursion will go only 1 level. All other validators should call `ValidateMembers(typeof(SomeType))` manually.

If you want *all* validators to recurse automatically, then create another base class that calls all required `ValidateMembers` in the constructor.

```cs
public class DefaultValidator<T>: RecursiveValidator<T> {
    public DefaultValidator<T>(IServiceProvider services): base(services) {
       ValidateMembers(typeof(User));
       ValidateMembers(typeof(Address));
       ValidateMembers(typeof(Project));
       ValidateMembers(typeof(PhoneNumber));

       // Or just a single base class
       ValidateMembers(typeof(BaseEntity));
    }
}
```

> Note: This implementation assumes you may have *multiple* validators for each type, and you want to run all of them. This is why the `IServiceProvider` is required. The standard `IValidatorFactory` only returns a single validator.